# could not be created because the data didn't validate

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-forms

I'm trying to use a ModelForm to create and save an object to my database, but I keep getting a ValueError telling me my data isn't validated once I submit the POST data. when I fill date from form I get a error, "could not be created because the data didn't validate"

This is in models.py

```
class BookPublishedOrder(models.Model):
    author_name = models.CharField(
        max_length=100, verbose_name="Author Name")
    author_summary = models.TextField(
        max_length=100, verbose_name="Author summary")
    book_title = models.CharField(
        max_length=100, verbose_name="Book Title")
    book_subtitle = models.CharField(
        max_length=100, verbose_name="Book Sub Title", blank=True)
    book_category = models.CharField(max_length=100,
                                     verbose_name="Book Category", blank=True)
    book_summary = models.TextField(
        max_length=100, verbose_name="Book summary")

    book_picture = models.ImageField(
        upload_to='Book Published Order', verbose_name="Book Picture", blank=True)
    email_address = models.CharField(
        max_length=100, verbose_name="Email Address")
    phone_number = models.CharField(
        max_length=100, verbose_name="Phone Number")
    facebook_account = models.CharField(
        _("Facebook Account"), max_length=200, blank=True)
    instgram_account = models.CharField(
        _("Instgram Account"), max_length=200, blank=True)
    twitter_account = models.CharField(
        _("Twitter Account"), max_length=200, blank=True)
    book_PDF = models.FileField(
        upload_to="Book PDF", verbose_name="Book PDF")

    class Meta:
        verbose_name = 'كتاب مطلوب للنشر'
        verbose_name_plural = 'الكتب المطلوبة للنشر'
```

This is in forms.py

```
class BookPublishedOrderForm(forms.ModelForm):
    author_name = forms.CharField(
        max_length=100, label="إسم الكاتب")
    author_summary = forms.CharField(label="ملخص عن الكاتب")
    book_title = forms.CharField(
        max_length=100, label="عنوان الكتاب")
    book_subtitle = forms.CharField(
        max_length=100, label="عنوان الفرعي للكتاب", required=False)
    book_category = forms.CharField(
        max_length=100, label="نوع الكتاب", help_text="100 characters max.", required=False)
    book_summary = forms.CharField(label="ملخص عن الكتاب")
    book_picture = forms.ImageField(label="غلاف الكتاب", widget=forms.FileInput(
        attrs={"class": "form-control"}))
    email_address = forms.CharField(
        max_length=300, label="البريد الإلكتروني")
    phone_number = forms.CharField(
        max_length=300, label="رقم التواصل")
    facebook_account = forms.CharField(
        max_length=300, label="حساب الفيسبوك", required=False)
    instgram_account = forms.CharField(
        max_length=300, label="حساب انستغرام", required=False)
    twitter_account = forms.CharField(
        max_length=300, label="حساب تويتر", required=False)
    book_PDF = forms.FileField(label="الكتاب (PDF)", widget=forms.FileInput(
        attrs={"class": "form-control"}))

    class Meta:
        model = BookPublishedOrder
        fields = "__all__"

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(BookPublishedOrderForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.fields['author_name'].widget = forms.TextInput(
            attrs={'placeholder': _("إسم الكاتب"), })
        self.fields['book_title'].widget = forms.TextInput(
            attrs={'placeholder': _("عنوان الكتاب"), })
        self.fields['book_subtitle'].widget = forms.TextInput(
            attrs={'placeholder': _("عنوان الفرعي للكتاب"), })
        self.fields['book_category'].widget = forms.TextInput(
            attrs={'placeholder': _("نوع الكتاب"), })
        self.fields['book_summary'].widget = forms.Textarea(
            attrs={'placeholder': _("ملخص عن الكتاب"), })
        self.fields['author_summary'].widget = forms.Textarea(
            attrs={'placeholder': _("ملخص الكاتب"), })
        self.fields['email_address'].widget = forms.TextInput(
            attrs={'placeholder': _("البريد الإلكتروني"), })
        self.fields['phone_number'].widget = forms.TextInput(
            attrs={'placeholder': _("رقم التواصل"), })
        self.fields['facebook_account'].widget = forms.TextInput(
            attrs={'placeholder': _("حساب الفيسبوك"), "class": "text-start"})
        self.fields['instgram_account'].widget = forms.TextInput(
            attrs={'placeholder': _("حساب انستغرام"), "class": "text-start"})
        self.fields['twitter_account'].widget = forms.TextInput(
            attrs={'placeholder': _("حساب تويتر"), "class": "text-start"})
```

This is in views.py

```
def publishbook(request):

    if request.method == "POST":
        formBookPublishedOrder = BookPublishedOrderForm(
            request.POST, request.FILES)
        if formBookPublishedOrder.is_valid:
            formBookPublishedOrder.save()
            print("from is not valid")
            print("from not valid")
    else:
        formBookPublishedOrder = BookPublishedOrderForm()
    context = {
        "title": "أنشر كتابك",
        "form": formBookPublishedOrder,
    }

    return render(request, 'publish-book-page.html', context)
```

I try to change

```
if formBookPublishedOrder.is_valid:
```

to

```
if formBookPublishedOrder.is_valid():
```

and didn't work

What I can do to fix this problem?

Comment: Normally the form will show *why* it is not valid...

Comment: You thus use `if formBookPublishedOrder.is_valid()`, which is the right way, and look what error is rendered when the form is rerendered.

Comment: I didn't understand ? how can I do that ?

Comment: @Abdelkader you just need to check the error that comes up when you validate the form using ```if formBookPublishedOrder.is_valid()```